# How do I reference Heroko Config Variables in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I've created a few variables to store API key and secrets in. But I don't understand how I'm supposed to reference those variables in my code. When I try to push up my code to Heroku it says that I have undefined constant variables. Which yes I do. So what do I have to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku's [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) are exposed to your app’s code as environmental variables. In Ruby you can access env vars through the `ENV` hash. This is actually just a plain old hash.

You can either use the [normal bracket accessors](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) or [Hash#key](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-key):

```
ENV['MY_SECRET_KEY']      # string / nil  
ENV.key('MY_SECRET_KEY')  # string / nil
ENV.key?('MY_SECRET_KEY') # true / false
```

You can also use [`Hash#fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) which lets you either raise an error if the key is missing or provide a default value:

```
ENV.fetch('MY_SECRET_KEY')             # raises a KeyError if the var is not set
ENV.fetch('MY_SECRET_KEY', 'abcd1234') # provides a default value
```

Raising an error can really help with troubleshooting as it will fail fast and tell you exactly where the problem is.